# match multiple array values, with value correct order

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have

```
 // the idea of the array below are ['from', 'to']
 var runA = [2,6]
 var runB = [4,1]

 var input = [1,4,2,6,2]
```

How can match store to `runA`, so that of `2,6` are in the correct order? It should return true.

But for `runB`, it should return false, even if it contains both values 1, and 4, but does not match the correct 'from', 'to' order.

Comment: Is it homework for us or you have tried some code yourself?

Comment: didnt thought of the regex, I converted the arrays to string try to pass it in character by character, if no consecutive 'true', than break loop and restart otherwise do callback... yup its a mess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible way:

```
if ( new RegExp("\\b" + runA + "\\b").test(input) ) {
    // 'runA' exists in 'input'
}
```

Comment: @gdoron It is even more elegant without `join()`

Comment: yep, it's by default when you `toString` an array(implicity here)